# Throttling at Office 365 Management Activity API

Tags: office365

Our multi-tenant system is using [Office 365 management activity API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-managment-apis-overview) to retrieve the data in the following approaches:

1. O365 activity data is stored as blocks identified by contentUri
2. For each tenant, retrieve contentUri list with start time and end time (we are breaking retrieval to 2 hours window), please see [activity API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference)
3. Then iterate through above contentUri list to retrieve the O365 activity data for current tenant.

We are facing throttling issue right now at above step #3 in some customers. For some very large customers in some regions, there could be a lot of contentUri.  We could only retrieve activity data for average 1 contentUri or a little bit more per second and 60 or less per minute which is very well below the 60k per minute stated at [activity API troubleshooting document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/troubleshooting-the-office-365-management-activity-api?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

We tried to improve the performance after trying all the following approaches without any success:

1. Decorate the http request with user agent as ISV/vendor name/product name
2. Retrieve in parallel with 2 – 5 threads: First request would be quick, then subsequent would be slow even with 2 requests in parallel
3. Office365 Management API is using PublishIdentifier to allocate the throttling quota about 60K request per minute per tenant as [activity API troubleshooting document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/troubleshooting-the-office-365-management-activity-api?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). We tried by having our company's tenant GUID (as ISV), customer tenant GUID or some random GUID as PublishIdentifier, and we didn’t see any performance improvement.
   [image]

Any suggestions for what we should do to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

As the doc tells:
*If you’re implementing a client for your company’s tenant, the PublisherIdentifier is the Tenant GUID. If you are creating an ISV application or add-in for multiple customers, the PublisherIdentifier should be the ISV’s Tenant GUID, and not the tenant GUID of end user’s company.*
And from my experience, the PublishIdentifier should be the tenant GUID where your APP is registered.

Comment: Thanks although it doesn't help for us though as we tried various value for PublishIdentifier per I stated above.